# data.table CJ set missing to zero

Tags: r, data.table

When using R, data.table's `CJ` provides a great way to fill in missing rows. It is possible to convert the NA values generated to zero by typing

```
DT[is.na(var), var := 0]
```

where `var` is the variable.

Is there a parameter within `CJ` itself that can fill in missing rows with 0 instead of NA? I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: No. But there are plans to have it eventually. This is equivalent to the following feature request: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/857